# Nested angular expressions

Tags: angularjs, json

I've two json as follows:

```
 users= [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "isActive": true,
          "age": 30,
          "name": "Hester Nunez",
          "dob": "10/12/2015",
          "email": "hesternunez@jasper.com",
          "phone": "+1 (975) 580-3067",
          "address": "918 Greenpoint Avenue, Elbert, Idaho, 7423"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "isActive": false,
          "age": 23,
          "name": "Hopkins Cantu",
          "gender": "male",
          "dob": "16/02/2011",
          "email": "hopkinscantu@xumonk.com",
          "phone": "+1 (966) 514-3562",
          "address": "332 Aurelia Court, Wright, New Mexico, 1481"
        }]


columns = [

        {
            "id": "column1",
            "key": "name",
            "title": "Name"
        },
        {
            "id": "column2",
            "key": "age",
            "title": "Age"
        },
        {
            "id": "column3",
            "key": "gender",
            "title": "Gender"
        },
        {
            "id": "column4",
            "key": "email",
            "title": "Email"
        },
        {
            "id": "column5",
            "key": "address",
            "title": "Address"
        }
    ]
```

To create a table of users I want to display the value of users based on the key of the column. Something like this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
     <td data-ng-repeat="column in columns">{{user.{{column.key}}}}</td>
</tr>
```

As expected I'm getting the following parse error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is not a valid identifier at column 6 of the expression [user.{{column.key] starting at [{{column.key].
```

Any suggestions on how to evaluate this nested expression?

Comment: use {{user[column.key]}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one :

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
     <td data-ng-repeat="column in columns">{{user[column.key]}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @ManojPaul, please do accept my answer if it helps you... :)

Comment: Please wait for 10 mins. SO is not allowing me to accept answer before 10 mins since I posted my question. :)